# java @Inject annotation returns null

Tags: java

I am trying to inject a method from another class, but it returns null and throws a NullPointerException. Please let me know what mistake am I doing here.

```
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/")
public class Employee {
    @Inject
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GET
    @Path("/empXml")
    @Produces({ "application/xml" })
    @RolesAllowed({"employee"})
    public String getHelloWorldXML() {
        return "<xml><result>" + employeeService.createHelloMessage("Employee") + "</result></xml>";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Employee em=new Employee();
        System.out.println(em.getHelloWorldXML()); //gives NPE
    }

}

public class EmployeeService {
    int x = 10;

    String createHelloMessage(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }

}
```

Comment: Why should it return anything other than `null`?

Comment: It is supposed to return "<xml><result>Hello Employee</result></xml>" message here.

Comment: Why should anything be injected in that field?

Comment: To inject EmployeeService class method into Employee class.

Comment: How do you think `@Inject` works?

Comment: Whenever we call @Inject on a class variable, all its methods, constructors, variables gets injected into that class variable?

Comment: For one, you don't _call_ `@Inject`. `@Inject` is an annotation. You need an annotation processor that will handle it. You haven't shown us such a thing.

Comment: I don't know that I need an annotation processor to handle @Inject. Can you please give me a simple example.

Comment: One is typically provided by your container or Jersey. But you haven't shown us any of that. I'd go back and read a tutorial or two about those technologies.

Comment: I am using JBOSS RESTEasy to develop this webservice. I googled to find an annotation processor for this, but couldn't find any. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added bean.xml file to my project's WEB-INF folder. And that solved the issue.

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

      <!-- An application that uses CDI must have a file named beans.xml. 
      The file can be completely empty (it has content only in certain 
      limited situations), but it must be present. -->

</beans>
```

Comment: This solved it for me, thank you very much. Though I don't know why we even need this file.